# How to extract arguments localized by a stringsdict file in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, localization

Is there a way to extract the localized word from a stringsdict file to perform a string comparison in code?

E.G.

`NSStringLocalizedFormatKey` : `%@ and %#@lu_total_users@ commented on your post`

Could produce an output of `John and 2 others commented on your post.`

The `2 others` part is generated from rules in the stringsdict file. I would like to add some string attributes (e.g. bold font) to that part of the text to produce an output like:

> John and **2 others** commented on your post.

Is this possible?

This is my stringsdict file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>activity.text.new_comment.group</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%@ and %#@lu_total_users@ commented on your post</string>
        <key>lu_total_users</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>lu</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>one other</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%lu others</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Not ideal but could you add some delimiters to plural string? So after it's gone through the localisation you could end up with something like - `John and <b>2 others</b> commented on your post`, which you could then perform a second sweep on.

Comment: Thanks, that could work. Will give that a go if I don't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the sentence into two rules in the stringsdict file. Take a look at the code and sample plist file below.

(I attempted to pass in a fourth argument with a second name and use that in the "one" case for the `more` key, but that doesn't work on my machine and shows string corruption. YMMV.)

In code:

```
int totalUsers = 2; // for example, obviously coming from somewhere else
int secondaryUsers = 0;
NSString *firstName = @"John";
if (totalUsers > 1) {
    secondaryUsers = totalUsers - 1;
}
NSString *commented =  [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"COMMENTED", @"Users who commented string"), totalUsers, secondaryUsers, firstName];
```

In your stringsdict file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>COMMENTED</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%1$#@users@</string>
            <key>users</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>%3$@ commented on your post.</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%3$@ and %2$#@more@ commented on your post.</string>
            </dict>
            <key>more</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%d others</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks @lensovet, but I don't quite get your solution. Do you mind providing a simple example on how the 2 strings `%d others` and `%@ and %@ commented on your post` are related in the `.strings` and `.stringsdict` files?

Comment: Yes, hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: just updated my answer with actual sample code, sorry for the delay…and then remembered why you wanted two strings…let me know if this is helpful at all.

Comment: Thanks @lensovet for providing the example, but I think I'm missing something here. How do you then extract the localized words to apply attributes (like bolding, etc)?

Answer (score -1):

Not ideal but could you add some delimiters to plural string? So after it's gone through the localisation you could end up with something like - John and **2 others** commented on your post, which you could then perform a second sweep on.